# How to remove .php, .html, .htm extensions with .htacess?

Tags: php, html

I'm Developing one website and want to remove the extensions from my website [s7info](https://s7info.in) in order to make the URLs more user and search friendly. I stumbled across tutorials on how to remove the .php extension from a PHP page. What about the .html? i want to remove those as well..!!

Comment: go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess

Comment: Read this https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Comment: Thanks for referral link ...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

**.htacess**  file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
#RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
#RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.html [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.htm -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.htm
#RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ $1.htm [NC]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks Dave for quick replay and its working it thanks a lot